# Formatting for keyboard shortcuts in comments

Tags: discussion, support, comments, formatting

Why is there no support for keyboard shortcuts to apply formatting (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for `code`) within comments to a post?

Comment: This is a feature I am missing as well!! BTW, for Code, I'd prefer Ctrl+Shift+C ;)

Comment: `you mean` **bolding** and *italics* don't work?

Comment: @Paulie_D He means that the keyboard shortcuts for adding the markdown for **bold** and *italics* don't work.  You have to type them out by hand.

Comment: No, I am asking about shorthands, like when you press **ctrl+B**,`ctrl+K` from keyboard, it should automatically convert the same, like you see in answer `textarea`

Comment: Exactly @Servy...

Comment: Web app keyboard shortcuts that shadow OS keyboard commands are the work of the devil.

Comment: @JoshCaswell And yet SO already has them, it just doesn't have them in comments.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Agree but however, SO have implemented the feature already for answer `textarea` right? Would it be difficult to provide the same to comments as well?

Comment: Oh, I know, @Servy, but already having made a poor decision is no reason to make another one.

Comment: I'm looking for why `<kbd>` tags render as a box/button in posts, but not in comments.  That's not what this question was actually about, so I edited it to reflect that.

Answer (score 6):

***"Why are there no keyboard shortcuts for comments"***
- Kind of, there are, but you have to install it yourself:

> ### [Add keyboard shortcuts to comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2103/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-comments)
>
> This script adds <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (bold), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (italic), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (code), and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (link) shortcuts to comments.

The working userscript is the one I posted as an answer. It's a pretty handy feature, I use it all the time.

Comment: I like you crazies who want such a feature installing a userscript much better than me having to install a userscript to _unbind_ these shortcuts. Cheers!

Comment: @Josh, I'm flagging you for your [duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308508/simple-time-saver-for-code-blocks#comment261342_308508) comments: [`Web app keyboard shortcuts that shadow OS keyboard commands are the work of the devil.`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308494/why-are-there-no-keyboard-shortcuts-for-comments#comment261119_308494) :D

Comment: Hey, it's not my fault that people keep proposing the same terrible idea. :)

Comment: Some feature-requests should prompt a warning when composing the question: "Did you already check Stack Apps?" (:

Comment: This is cool!! Never thought its so simple to achieve this.. :) Thank you.. :)

Comment: @brasofilo, I installed scripts but am getting **`Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined`** and everything stops working.. :(

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, please, report this at Stack Apps and specify your browser and extension.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is a reason for the feature not existing currently: comments are second-class citizens.  In general, comments shouldn't need that much formatting.  If you find yourself making these heavily formatted comments, it's probably time to add/edit a post instead.

Among other reasons, community feedback (via voting and comments) is an integral part of a post, but that feedback is lacking for comments.  Which is why posts are preferred over comments. Making it easy to format comments would further encourage overuse of comments over posts. This is probably why SO hasn't supported full markdown, a WYSIWYG editor, or formatting shortcuts for comments.

Comment: I treat my comments as first-class communication tools. If we are able to format it, being second-class *content* is not a reason not to have the shortcuts. I'm sure there are valid reasons not to implement it, from economy to dev-time but I don't buy the "second citizen" argument.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are second-hand citizens.  If you're really putting that much effort into a comment (that backticks ``` `` ```  can't solve), you should consider posting an answer or making an edit instead.  Even chat would be a better option.  Remember that comments are subject to clean up at any time, so all that work could really be for nothing unless it's part of a post.

Comment: Many times I realised that comments are really important part to judge if the answer is really usefull or not.. when there are dozens of answer available to single question

Comment: Comments being second-class citizens is *not* an excuse for lack of useful functionality.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thank you for support.. I feel same thing and agree with you

Comment: @Kushal: Is that because the answer is lacking some important content, meaning the comment should be incorporated?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Can we add that feature?

Comment: @DaniSpringer The question is a [meta-tag:discussion] not a [meta-tag:feature-request].  So this is an answer to the question "Why is there no keyboard support for comments?"

Comment: It had the feature-request tag.

Comment: @DaniSpringer I don't think so.  Check the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/294392/revisions)

Comment: I must have mixed up with a different question.