# Why are there no keyboard shortcuts for comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, editor

Why aren't there any keyboard shortcuts for comments like in a post? For example, shortcuts like 
<kbd>`ctrl+K`</kbd> for `code` , <kbd>`ctrl+B`</kbd> to `bold` the text.

I'm not asking for every shortcut possible, but at least for `Code`, `Bold`, `Italic` and other basic stuff. Is there any reason for not including this feature?