# Could we implement formatting keyboard shortcuts for comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, formatting

Could we have comment formatting a bit easier by having keyboard shortcuts similar to those in question and answer editor?

For example when pressing <kbd>Ctrl + I</kbd> with a word selected in comment editor, it would produce:

```
_Selected text_
```

When <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd>, it would be:

```
**Selected text**
```

And so on... (just don't know how to deal with links; in question and answer editor it pops a dialog)

---

<sup>I've seen [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308494/8041231), but I'm not asking why it's not implemented,
 I'm asking if we can implement this feature.</sup>

Comment: If I *had* to guess, I would imagine the reason why it's not getting implemented is [provided in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308497/1079354).

Comment: @Makoto, could be, but it would be nice to have it (and I believe easy to implement). Hence I'm not asking why, but if we could implement them :)