# Simple time-saver for code blocks

Tags: feature-request

It would be very convenient if double-clicking a code block selected the entire contents both for backtick and block types.

Comment: It would also be really annoying if it did so, when you're expecting it to only select a single word (which is what most browsers will do on a double click).

Comment: How many times have you used the "single word" feature? In the last decade? I'd bet it's a lot fewer than the number of times you've needed to select the entire contents of a quoted block.

Comment: A rough estimate for the last year would be 3000. Extrapolate that out if you like. My use of it hasn't been consistent between jobs (some being much more terminal based, or working on tasks where there's less need for such). For a single website to change that behaviour would be horrendously arrogant.

Comment: In a browser, specifically. Expecting your terminal and your browser to operate alike is foolishness, unless your browser is Links.

Comment: Well, most terminal *clients* will. Putty does. Terminal on Mac OSX does. The default gnome one does. But yes, that 3,000 in the last year is primarily selecting words in web browsers and / or text editors.

Comment: The hijacking of established OS input device commands by a web app is the work of the devil. This would be extremely _in_convenient.

Answer (score 8):

No need to hijack existing mouse gestures when others exist.

Double-click to select a word, and then drag across the inline code span to select more words.

Triple-click within a code block to select a line, and then drag down the code block to select more lines.

Should work in most browsers and platforms.

Comment: No, it works in IE and Chrome; it does not work in Firefox. Besides, that's considerably more actions (double click, hold, drag to position) than a simple double-click. I've occasionally needed to triple click when I wanted an entire line, but I'd bet you that virtually nobody actually needs the "whole word" feature being "hijacked" by this change.

Comment: That's strange. It's worked for me in every version of Firefox I've used on both Windows and OS X in the last decade.

Comment: Huh. Well, my profile is ancient and probably highly customized--I can't even recall have the tweaks I've made over the years. Perhaps I disabled that somehow.

Comment: I'd much rather go through more actions with the assurance that they will work consistently than have to consciously remember each time that double-clicking a code block will select the entire thing rather than a single word as I'd expect. But that's just me.

Comment: Never underestimate the power of muscle memory.

Comment: Works for me in Firefox (and always has).

Comment: @BoltClock I went from 200 WPM in QWERTY to using Dvorak in an afternoon. Yes, I know how hard it is to break muscle memory--of course, after doing that, nothing else seems all that difficult in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/5038/34182).

It's primarily meant for indentation handling (<kbd>Tab</kbd> behaving like in Notepad++, and smart indent on <kbd>Enter</kbd>), but it also has the feature you requested here.

FWIW, I use that script, and I like the indentation part but I absolutely hate that double-click thing :-)